# What is a .p12, .cer, .csr, .jks, .pem file?

Tags: ssl, soap, certificate, ssl-certificate, soapui

I'm implementing a SOAP service with SoapUI that needs authentication.

For authentication, I received 5 files:

> XXX.cer
>   XXX.csr
>   XXX.jks
>   XXX.p12
>   XXX.pem

I used the "XXX.p12" file with SoapUI to authenticate.

What is the purpose of each file and why do I need the ".p12" to gain access to the WSDL?

Comment: [literally the first google result](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/create-a-pfx-p12-certificate-file-using-openssl/)

Comment: @Sam So we deleted SOEn because literally everything is found on Google, and your link does not answer my question, but thank you anyway.

Comment: This is still a good question and I still don't understand what the different file extensions mean.

Answer (score 1):

The PKCS#12 or PFX format is a binary format for storing the server certificate, any intermediate certificates, and the private key in one encryptable file. PFX files usually have extensions such as .pfx and .p12. PFX files are typically used on Windows machines to import and export certificates and private keys.